# Why is Debian 6.0.1 asking for Install CD when installing stuff?

Tags: debian, apt, installation

I've recently installed a Debian 6.0.1 and when i issue the simple apt-get, when finishing (99% says) ask for the install CD.

> Cambio de medio: Por favor, inserte el
>   disco etiquetado como  «Debian
>   GNU/Linux 6.0.1a *Squeeze* - Official
>   i386 CD Binary-1 20110322-15:11» en la
>   unidad «/media/cdrom/» y pulse Intro

Something like:

> Change the source: Please, insert the
>   CD labeled as «Debian GNU/Linux 6.0.1a
>   *Squeeze* - official i386 CD Binary-1 20110322-15:11» in  «/media/cdrom/» 
>   and press Intro (Return)

Can you tell me why is it and how can i fix it. I don't want to let the CD in the server.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your /etc/apt/sources.list is referencing the cd.  If you remove it, it will purely use the net to download any files.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I'll try it. Seems to be the rigth thing to do.